# Creating a Crucible review for a whole project

Tags: svn, atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible

I'm looking a way to create a code review on a whole project/branch, independently if the files that has been modified and the usual revisions paradigm.

Basically, I want a review without diffs that will present the latest version of the code including files unchanged for months/years, or even not changed at all (in a given branch, so identical from the trunk from where it was copied).

I'm using SVN with the usual trunk/tags/branches standard.

Thanks,

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking for. How would your review work? Are you planning to compare a branch with its parent (usually trunk)?

Comment: No, I don't want to compare anything. I would like to see the latest version of the code (at code review creation time) and use Crucible to add comments/suggestions on that code. Basically, I want to comment on the code in general as opposed as commenting specific changes as we do usually with Crucible.

Comment: Then, simply checkout the latest version of the code.: [`svn checkout URL WC_PATH`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html).

Comment: I tough about that :-) But I would like to use the Crucible features to comment the code and have exchange with team mates (we have remote teams in different timezones, so Crucible is a good way to communicate for us).

Comment: Sounds like you should just create an overview document (maybe a text file, nothing fancy) that contains your review, and commit that to the repo. I realize this doesn't use Crucible, but it seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: By the way, if your project is sufficiently large (more than 800 files), Crucible won't let you create a review ticket for all its files.

Answer (score 7):

The compiledammit URL is broken, and SO guidelines state that answers with actual code/instructions are preferred over those that just reference a link, so here's what I figured out myself:

```
select revisions from dir /your-project-name
where is head
and not is deleted
group by path
```

EyeQL latest reference guide:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/eyeql-reference-guide-298976796.html

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, and some info in this answer is old too. There may have been some progress on Crucible from Atlassian since the following information was found.

Apparently Crucible does not directly support adding all files from a folder to a review. Instead, you must either add each individually, or add the result of a search to the review.

The latter involves creating a custom search for the files you need.  This is described in a blog article I found here:
http://compiledammit.com/2012/12/04/adding-all-project-files-to-a-crucible-review/